# Pulling information from HTML div boxes with the same name using python

Tags: python, html, loops, web-scraping, beautifulsoup

So basically I've been trying to work out how to scrape bigo.tv chat, the first problem I've encountered is how I would extract each message sent to the chat, firstly as each chat message that is sent it's given the same div container id, and the class of the div box differs from the kind of message sent (type1=chatMessages, type6=gifts), I've attached a screenshot demonstrating the HTML structure of a type 6 chat message (gift), I'm a very basic python programmer and I'm willing to learn and expand my knowledge, I'm just lost at where I would start, and have no friends interested in this subject to speak with.

[html structure of a type6 chat message (gift)](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WEeBx.png)

What I'm expecting to accomplish with this script:

- Extract the (user level, user name, user message/gift) into a separate text file according to div class(type1, type6, etc.).
- the script must continuously run throughout the live stream but not repeat any entry it's already entered.

like I said I'm not asking for code but pointers in the right direction would be really really helpful! I have been looking at beautifulsoup4 but again as an amature Python programmer, I'm struggling to find a starting point.

this is the code I've tried to use to get at least one chat message without success.

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

r=requests.get("https://www.bigo.tv/875643864")
soup=BeautifulSoup(r.content,"html.parser")
div_text=soup.find("div",{"class":"user-text-content"}).get_text()
print(div_text)
```

I've had to include a photo of the error as I can't copy and paste it as I'm on a Chromebook and using pydroid3

[terminal error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/aFCdV.png)

Comment: or would urllib be the way to go? Please any help would be grateful!

Comment: Please don't post images of code, errors, logs, or other text; see [ask]. Instead [edit] your question and include your code, even if it's only attempts that don't work. That way we have something to work with, and won't suggest something you've already tried.

Comment: You have to login to chat or even see the messages; while it probably is possible to log in with requests, I'd suggest trying [selenium](https://medium.com/ymedialabs-innovation/2f8ad15efe25), especially since it looks like you might need something that supports javascript

Comment: @Driftr95 thanks for the reply, selenium is the way I have chosen to go, I now have a script that will collect the first username and message and add it to a data table but I'm struggling for it to wait until it collects more, as of right now it will just spit out the first message and repeat it however many times I specify. Would I be able to private message you and maybe you could take a look at what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

You are on the right track using BeautifulSoup and Requests for web scraping. However, you might encounter errors if the element you are trying to find does not exist on the page. To handle such cases, you should check if the element exists before attempting to access its attributes.

Here's a simple code snippet to get you started with extracting chat messages:

```
from bs4 import BeautifulSoup
import requests

def scrape_chat_messages():
    url = "https://www.bigo.tv/875643864"
    r = requests.get(url)
    soup = BeautifulSoup(r.content, "html.parser")

    chat_messages = []

    # Find all chat message elements
    chat_elements = soup.find_all("div", {"class": "user-text-content"})

    for chat_element in chat_elements:
        # Extract the user level, user name, and user message/gift from the chat element
        user_level = chat_element.find("span", {"class": "user-level"}).get_text()
        user_name = chat_element.find("span", {"class": "user-name"}).get_text()
        user_message = chat_element.find("span", {"class": "message"}).get_text()

        # Append the extracted chat message to the list
        chat_messages.append({
            "user_level": user_level,
            "user_name": user_name,
            "user_message": user_message
        })

    return chat_messages

if __name__ == "__main__":
    messages = scrape_chat_messages()
    print(messages)
```